# How to alter my CSS to ensure that the textarea height always matches the height of its div container?

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea inside a div, and I wish for the text area height to match the height of the div container.

Currently, the width fits perfectly, however the textbox (which begins empty) only fills about 20% of the div height.

And when an ajax call grabs some text and populates the textarea, the textarea height remains at about 20% of the div and provides a scroll bar.

How can I alter my CSS to ensure that the textarea height always matches the height of its div container?

```css
#answerBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

#answerBoxDiv {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 4px solid #00bfb6;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerBoxDiv">
  <textarea id="answerBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set a height of the parent container (whether that is in px or rem etc) - that way the height: 100% of the textarea will fill to the container.

The expand on text content cannot be done with simple css - you need js to determine the heaight of the content and adjust the parent container accordingly.

The only way tyou can keep height: 100% on the parent container is its ancestor has a height set (eg 100vh) - that way the browser can determine the height of each DOM element and size the text area accrodingly.

**UPDATE - I have added a js function to automatiucally increae the height of the parent container on the input. (the textarea autoincreases in height since it is 100% of the parentThis will need massaging - but when you type into the textarea the height will auto expand.**

```js
function setHeight(element) {
  const container = document.getElementById("answerBoxDiv");
  const height = element.scrollHeight;
  if(height > 100) {
    container.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
    }
}
```

```css
#answerBoxDiv {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px; **// this is needed - but can be in px / rem / vh or other but NOT % unless its parent has its height set.**
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 4px solid #00bfb6;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

#answerBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="answerBoxDiv">
   <textarea id="answerBox" oninput="setHeight(this)"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Glaf you like it - note I have updated the answerr to provide an autoexpand function for the textarea on input - eg - it starts at 150px - then on the user typing - when it exceeds that height - it will re-set the height on both the container and textarea. As a fun aside - this will also autoshrink the textarea when the user deletes content from the input  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Percentage height does not work with a min-height parent, you would either need to give your parent a height or you could use flex:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#answerBox {
  flex-grow:1;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

#answerBoxDiv {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 4px solid #00bfb6;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="answerBoxDiv">
  <textarea id="answerBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try keeping the min-height of the textarea as 100% or nearby or try using
`object-fit: contain(or cover)` on your text area

Comment: Thank you, I've changed to min-height and tried object-fit, but unfortunately they have not helped in this situation.

Comment: try `object-fit: cover`

Comment: or possibly use this
#answerBox::after{
min-height: 100%
}

Comment: Unfortunately neither are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#answerBox {
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this has not helped in my situation.

Comment: Let me look at it when I get home

Answer (score 0):

Give specific `height` for #answerBoxDiv parent div. So you will get appropriate height for this div.

```
<div class="parent-div" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="answerBoxDiv">
        <textarea id="answerBox"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```